# How can I change a parent state through a react navigation component?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm new to React Native and having trouble figuring out how to accomplish this. Currently I have an app structure something like this:

App.js -> Authentication.js -> if(state.isAuthenticated) Homepage.js, else Login.js

I'm currently changing the isAuthenticated state on a logout button on the homepage. I'm now trying to add in a drawer navigator to the app, which would get returned to the authentication page in place of the homepage. So I'm not sure how to pass the state change through the drawernavigator component to the Authentication page.

Currently my Homepage has a button that has:

```
onPress={() => this.props.logout()}
```

And the authentication page has:

```
export default class Authentication extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isAuthenticated: false,
      isLoading: false
    }

    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
  }

  login() {
    AsyncStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify({email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password}))
      .then(results => {
        this.setState({isAuthenticated: true});
      });
  }

  logout() {
    AsyncStorage.clear()
      .then(result => {
          this.setState({isAuthenticated: false});
      });
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({isLoading: true});
    AsyncStorage.getItem("user")
        .then(results => {
          const data = JSON.parse(results);
          if (data) {
            this.setState({isAuthenticated: true});
          }
          this.setState({isLoading: false});
        });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading){
      return(
        <Splashpage />
      );
    }
    if (!this.state.isAuthenticated){
      return (
        <Login login={this.login}/>
      );
    }
    return (
      <Homepage logout={this.logout}/>
    );
  }
}
```

So I made a Navigation.js page where I'm creating a drawernavigator and going to be returning this instead of the Homepage.

```
export default Navigation = createDrawerNavigator({
    Home: {
      screen: Homepage,
    },
    WebView: {
      screen: WebView,
    },
});
```

But I'm not sure how to pass along the state change from the homepage, through the Navigation component to the parent Authentication page.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a callback through navigate:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('yourTarget',{callback:function});
```

In yourTraget you can access it via:

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.callback(isAuthenticated)
```

Here the documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html

I hope this is what you were looking for! Oh now I see you asked that already a while ago. Maybe you already moved on...